# Missing file through getAssets

Tags: java, android

I have a problem connected with reading a file in Java Application. Please help me as I'm trying to do it for  four days and my CS teacher is not into Android Apps. Also any of the tutorials read does not help me.

I have a following app:

```
        package com.bachosz.billionaires;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


    public class MainActivityBillionaires extends ActionBarActivity {

        private int currentQuestion;
        private String [] answers;
        private Button answerButton;
        private Button questionButton;
        private TextView questionView;
        private TextView answerView;
        private EditText answerText; 
        private Question [] questions;
        private Button buttonA;
        private Button buttonB;
        private Button buttonC;
        private Button buttonD;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_billionaires);

        try {
            init();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

        public void init() throws IOException
        {
            questions = new Question[2];
            currentQuestion = 0;
            InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.questionstable);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = null;
              String content,a,b,c,d,correct;
                int id, x = 0;
                StringTokenizer st = null;
            while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                 st= new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
                    id = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    content = st.nextToken();
                    a = st.nextToken();
                    b = st.nextToken();
                    c = st.nextToken();
                    d = st.nextToken();
                    correct = st.nextToken();

                    questions[x] = new Question(id, content, a, b, c, d, correct);
                    x++;
            }
            reader.close();


        answerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AnswerButton);
        questionButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.QuestionButton);
        questionView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.QuestionTextView);
        answerView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerTextView);
        answerText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AnswerText);
        buttonA = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
        buttonB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
        buttonC = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
        buttonD = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonD);



        answerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
       public void onClick(View v) {
       checkAnswer();
       }});



        questionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
       showQuestion();
       }});
        }

        public void showQuestion()
        {

      // if(currentQuestion == questions.length)
       // currentQuestion =0;       

        questionView.setText(questions[0].toString());
        answerView.setText("");
        answerText.setText("");
        currentQuestion++;

        }

        public boolean isCorrect(String answer)
        {
        return (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(questions[currentQuestion].getCorrect()));
        }

        public void checkRight()
        {
        //  String right
        }
        public void checkAnswer()
        {
        String answer = questions[currentQuestion].getCorrect();
        if(isCorrect(answer))
        answerView.setText("You're right!");
        else
        answerView.setText("Sorry, the correct answer is "+answers[currentQuestion]);

        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_billionaires, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

It is taken from Java application I was writing previously (that is why so many comments). How I can access the fileName in Android App? I was trying InputStream, get Assets, etc. but It does not work or I am doing it improperly. Currently it is throwing NullPointerException.

LOG CAT:

```
10-09 13:38:37.663: E/Trace(921): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-09 13:38:39.354: D/AndroidRuntime(921): Shutting down VM
10-09 13:38:39.354: W/dalvikvm(921): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bachosz.billionaires/com.bachosz.billionaires.MainActivityBillionaires}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at com.bachosz.billionaires.MainActivityBillionaires.readFile(MainActivityBillionaires.java:111)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at com.bachosz.billionaires.MainActivityBillionaires.init(MainActivityBillionaires.java:140)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at com.bachosz.billionaires.MainActivityBillionaires.onCreate(MainActivityBillionaires.java:70)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-09 13:38:39.384: E/AndroidRuntime(921):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you please post your full exception from logcat.

Comment: Done :) hope it helps.

Comment: Line 111 is with this function     currentQuestion++;
     if(currentQuestion == questions.length)
     currentQuestion =0;
     questionView.setText(questions[currentQuestion].getContent());
     answerView.setText("");
     answerText.setText("");                                               It sets error because the array questions does not exist because the txt file is not found.

Answer (score 0):

The error says you're getting a NPE (Null Pointer Exception) at `com.bachosz.billionaires.MainActivityBillionaires`. You need to look at the code section that you use to call that activity. (it is not in your code above - or else we don't know which line with the given information)

Another thing you have to make sure is that you have the appropriate context.

```
AssetManager assetManage = appContext.getAssets();
String[] filelist = assetManage.list("");
```

Comment: Thank you for respond. However, I do not call the MainActivity, it just starts the application. I've updated the code to show you the full MainActivity. I still get the error, even after adding appContext.

Answer (score 0):

First you should clean up your code, at least to show it here where we don't know what are you doing.
It's easier to understand.

Why are you using assets? In Android the most common way to access resources is the .../res/raw folder.
It makes a reference of the file in the autogenerated R.class so you can access it anywhere.
Make sure your filename is lowercase and has no spaces. If you haven't raw folder under res, create it manually.

Try this:

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.YOURFILE);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null)
{
    // Read file.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have used it, but still I get null null when accessing data. I've updated the code. I'd be grateful if you looked it up.

Comment: May the reason be that I am running it from pendrive?

Comment: You're welcome. What is the **exact** statment where you get the NullPointerException? And what do you mean with you're running from pendrive?? :)

Comment: I have my working space and Project on pendrive. I'm pretty annoyed with it as it is still not working :/. Currentyl the logCat and debuger window don't want to open...

Comment: questionView.setText(questions[currentQuestion].getContent()); that's the line. But the error is because questions table is empty (I've checked it and it's null null null). So, the file formula still does not work :/.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly:  copy YOURFILE to assets folder.

Then,   `AssetManager assetManage = getAssets();`

Then,

```
    InputStream myInput = null;
    try {
        myInput = assetManager.open("YOURFILE");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And finally  `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myInput));`

follow the above code step by step.